# Can't retrieve image from web in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms

In the viewmodel of my page, I try to get an image to show. This image I get from one of our webservice. The image source is stored in ProductImage

```
string path = $@"http://www.MyCompany.be/cdn-cgi/image/width=150,quality=75/images/products/{CurrentProduct.Image}".Replace($"\\", $"/");

ProductImage = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(path));
```

I of course make sure when I update the Image source for the view when I change it

```
public ImageSource ProductImage
    {

        get
        {
            return _productImage;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_productImage != value)
            {
                _productImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Sadly, for some reason it doesn't work. I checked the URL called and it does lead to an image.
It used to work when I was using streams instead of calling an URL. I know I haven't put the safety checks around yet to make sure the image exist, but other than that nothing has changed. I save the image the exact same way, i just use fromUri rather than fromStream.

```
            //Get target's SmbFile.
            var file = new SmbFile(path, auth);
            try
            {
                if (file.Exists())
                {
                    // Get readable stream.
                    var readStream = file.GetInputStream();

                    //Create reading buffer.
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

                    //Get bytes.
                    ((Stream)readStream).CopyTo(memStream);

                    var stream1 = new MemoryStream(memStream.ToArray());

                    if (stream1.Length < 30000000)
                    {
                        //Save image
                        //ProductImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);

                        //Dispose readable stream.
                        readStream.Dispose();

                        InfoColSpan = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Common.AlertError("Image trop lourde pour l'affichage");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.AlertError(ex, "Impossible de charger l'image");
            }
```

Since I changed my method, I no longer load anything.

Comment: your old method is using `SmbFile` which is typically used for files that are not publicly available via a url.  Have you tested one of your urls using the browser on your device to verify that it loads?

Comment: @Jason Yes, i checked. When opening the web browser on the devicce and typing the full URL, I do get the image.

Comment: You are also using `http`, there are default restrictions in both iOS an Android about using non-secure urls

Comment: @Jason I think I found something as some image started working. It looks like they're now in cache. Maybe it doesn't show the image because it isn't loaded yet when the Imagesource is refreshed? I'll look up if there is a way to load.

Comment: You try to add a breakpoint to the line `ProductImage = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(path));` to see what the obtained value is.